# How might I use $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'] in the context of OpenAM Single SIgn on to allow users to authenticate?

Tags: single-sign-on

At an institution they use Sun's OpenAM SSO Enterprise, which after a successful login with the inistuations' SSO, places the username inside of [$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19681-01/820-5816/gawim/index.html).

First, is it possible to take advanced of this, supplanting the WP login functionality in favor of using SSO? If this is possible, what is a best-practice method of doing so? Is there a preferred plugin which already has such functionality built?

Comment: yes you cam but this is a very bad question.....

Comment: Any chance you'd be willing to make suggestions to improve this question?

Comment: it is a yes/no question. No one probably knows what is openSSO and how it is supposed to be used. Is it a "off band" authentication that still needs to create cookies or is it going to be used in a kind of server to server protocol like XML-RPC/SOAP. Rule of thumb for a good question is that it doesn't include external links (not many follow them as especially in this question the impression is that it will lead to a long article) and have enough details for whoever reading to be able to estimate if he knows what the problem is without additional research. cont....

Comment: The more obscure the question is the more details should be given, and more research needs to be done before asking (maybe ask smaller questions while researching). And of course this is just a rule of thumb, some times good questions will not get any answer and bad ones will get a perfect one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled upon this module called [OpenAM Authentication](https://wordpress.org/plugins/openam-authentication/) that I'm going to experiment with on a development server. Merely reading the plugin's [FAQ page](https://wordpress.org/plugins/openam-authentication/faq/) has me very hopeful